# Create images with Different format with Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, shapes

I want to create images at runtime with different format and color, here are some sample images that I want to create and my text in it..

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I will write text to any format and particular format will be created
Please give me some clue, so that I solve.

here is an running [Example](http://cheerzone.com/Lettering/ImageGenerator.aspx?text=AKHTAR&font_family=Broadway&layout_style=DoubleArch&background_style=TwoColorOval&color_style=TwoColors&color1=FFD700&color2=32CD32&color3=800080&width=400)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need should be available in the `System.Drawing` namespace

Some example projects on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/)

- [Create Dynamic Images in ASP.NET - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/Dynamic_Image_-_Extention.aspx)
- [Another Dynamic ASP.NET Text Image - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/DynamicASPDotNETTextImage.aspx)

---

[AForge.NET](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) and [ImageMagick.NET](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/) are two other image manipulation open-source libraries for some additional bells and whistles